# How can you handle touching a link within a UIWebView when you have a UIView overlay directly on top of it?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, overlay

I've been researching how to use a UIWebView embedded in a UIScrollView for a while now and cant seem to find an easy fix to my problem. I'm using a UIWebView because a UITextView, although allowing hyperlinks, does not allow you to change the link color from the standard blue apple sets.

But using a UIWebView introduces another problem: **It blocks the UIScrollView it is embedded in from handling scroll events because a UIWebView handles these events within its own private implementation.**

Although this allows me to use its embedded links, the UIWebView absorbs the touch events which doesn't allow me to scroll up/down when dragging within the UIWebView itself. I worked around this problem by placing a transparent UIView overlay exactly over the UIWebView, intercepting the touch events that it receives, and resigning it as first responder so that the UIScrollView that they are both subviews of can handle the scrolling appropriately.

Now, however, I can't seem to think of solution to the new problem this introduces: **I can't click on the links within my UIWebView that is right under the UIView Overlay.**

What is the best way to forward touch events to a UIWebView that is right underneath my transparent UIView in order to trigger my UIWebView's delegate method 'webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:' for tapping on links?

Answer (score -1):

FYI from UIWebView API doc:

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Back to the question,

UIWebView has property called scrollView, try doing:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnable = NO;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "What is the best way to forward touch events to a UIWebView that is right underneath my transparent UIView", which is the central issue.